# Wait in Selenium not functioning for a given element

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, css-selectors, wait

I am attempting to make WebDriver wait for an element to appear, but I only have a few bits of code to go off. Heres the html body content for the button;

```
<input class="btn" value="Analyze" type="button" data-bind="click:$root.windowsAnalysis.analyzeFilesClick,enable:$root.windowsAnalysis.analyzeFilesEnabled">
```

I have added the below line to my test but it is not making the WebDriver 'Wait'.

```
 new WebDriverWait(Login.driver,10).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf
(Login.driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[@class='btn'][@value='Analyze']"))));
```

Any ideas?

Many Thanks in advance

Comment: Issue seemed to be with the cssSelector. I replaced this with an xpath reference and the script is now executing, and waiting, as required. Happy to close this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Problem is with your CSS path,

```
By.cssSelector("input[@class='btn'][@value='Analyze']");
```

the @ before the class and value is not valid, it should be,

```
By.cssSelector("input[class='btn'][value='Analyze']");
```

Comment: Thank you Vignesh. As commented I had replaced the 'cssSelector' with an 'xpath' to resolve initially. I have implemented your solution in the code and that works great, script completes without error.